# Data Providers in Yii Unit Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

I am using Yii 1.1.7. I just got introduced to unit testing in Yii, I have installed and configured PHPUnit. I can run some basic test successfully. I want to know how (if possible), can I use data providers to execute my tests.

Here is my sample Test class:

```
<?php

   require_once('bootstrap.php');

   class SampleControllerTest extends CTestCase{

/*
 *  @dataProvider provider
 */
public function testSampleMethod($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)
{
   $this->assertGreaterThan(0,$ApplicationID);
}


public function provider()
{
    return array(
      array("1875","1","1","False"),
      array("1874","1","1","False"),
      array("1415","1","1","False"),
      array("1414","1","1","False"),
      array("1413","1","1","False"),
    );

}


   }

?>
```

When I run the test on PHPUnit, I get the following error:

**Missing Argument 1 for SampleController::testSampleMethod()**

I understand Functional testing is better for Controllers, and Unit testing for Models. I am just trying to get the data Provider running.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, The Error is **Missing Argument 1 for SampleControllerTest::testSampleMethod()**

Comment: Sorry about this, but the code in the testSampleMethod is : **$this->assertGreaterThan(0,$param1);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testSampleMethod because your method name starts with the word test then it is run by Yii when it runs tests. But it cannot have parameters, as it gets called automatically, how would Yii know what are you trying to use the array to call that function.

You can probably do a

```
/*
 *  @dataProvider provider
 */
public function checkSampleMethod($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)
{
   $this->assertGreaterThan(0,$ApplicationID);
}

/*
 *  @dataProvider provider
 */
public function testSampleMethod()
{
    foreach($this->provider() as $params) {
        list($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4) = $params;
        $this->checkSampleMethod($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4);
    }
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: This works, I am not sure if it is the right way to do it, but, it does run the tests. Thank you Mihai P, a very interesting way to execute testing.

Comment: You might try fixtures instead of your function. Also I see you are trying to test the controller with phpunit (without selenium). I found these links that tell you how to do this http://mattmccormick.ca/2012/09/14/unit-testing-url-routes-in-yii-framework/
http://insperedia.blogspot.com.au/
http://enginedave.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/writing-a-simple-unit-test/ . I have not tried them yet as I have selenium testing up and running but that runs quite slow so I might give these a go.

Comment: Of course testing without selenium does not test all the javascript goodies that come with Yii.

Comment: Thank you Mihai P, you are right in your assumption. These links are very useful, thanks once again.

Comment: no worries, the questions asked here on Yii are so basic that I find it refreshing to see some good practices :)